# Flutter, "The method 'map' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'."

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

I am getting this error when I am trying to call the .map method on the snapshot.data. I am using an SQLite database.

The code throwing the error is the following:

```
FutureBuilder(
                future: _alarms,
                builder: (context, snapshot)
                {
                  if(snapshot.hasData){
                  return ListView(
                    children: snapshot.data.map<Widget>((alarms) {
                      return Container(
```

And I am creating the _alarms list in the initState method:

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    _alarmHelper.initializeDatabase().then((value) => print('------------dB initialized'));
    _alarms = _alarmHelper.getAlarm();
    super.initState();
  }
```

And the .getAlarm(), is defined so:

```
 Future<List<AlarmInfo>> getAlarm() async{
    var result;
    var db = await this.database;

      result = await db?.query(tableName);

     result.forEach((element) { 
      var alarmInfo  = AlarmInfo.fromMap(element);
      alarms.add(alarmInfo);
      }
      );

      return alarms;
  }
```

I have also tried adding a ?. operator, but then this returns another error which is the .map is not defined for the type object `children: snapshot.data?.map<Widget>((alarms) {`

Any help is appreciated and if you require any further information feel free to leave a comment.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume it's because you didn't provide a type for the `FutureBuilder` widget, therefore `snapshot.data` is from type `Object` (instead of a list you are expecting there) and the `map` function does not exist for that.

It should be fixed by writing it like this:

```
FutureBuilder<List<AlarmInfo>>(
   ...
),
```

Additionally since `data` might be null (but you checked it with `snapshot.hasData` you have to write:

```
snapshot.data!.map(...)
```